# Working with custom modules having asynchronous code node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous-javascript

So, I have a file data.js(the custom module) with the following rough code(to not waste time understanding the whole code):

```
let data;

async function(){
    data = await something; //the await returns an array, so data has an array
}

module.exports={data} // I am exporting the data array
```

Now I am requiring the module in app.js

```
data=require("./data.js");

//Now I am using express to send json data to a url
app.get("/home",(req,res)=>{
    res.json(data);
});
```

So now if I open the url(localhost:5000/home) I am getting:

```
{}
```

Now if I modify data.js to

```
let data=[]; //I made data an empty array first

async function(){
    data = await something; //the await returns an array, so data has an array
}

module.exports={data} // I am exporting the data array
```

So now if I open the url(localhost:5000/home) I am getting:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Now if I modify data.js again

```
let data=[]; //I made data an empty array first

async function(){
    data.push(await something); //the await returns an array, and I am pushing into the empty array
}

module.exports={data} // I am exporting the data array
```

So now if I open the url(localhost:5000/home) finally I am getting:

```
{"data":[some data]}  //This is how I want
```

So I want to understand what's the difference between the three data.js files and how exactly does require work with the asynchronous code in the custom module.
If I console.log(data) in the app.js file I get empty which is understandable as that is synchronously happening before the asynchronous code of the custom module. But please would someone be able to explain why the first two methods of data.js is not working.

Sorry for the long question!

Comment: `module.exports={data}` does access the current value of the variable `data`, just like `console.log(data)` does - synchronously, before your code does reassign the variable. Using `push` instead does modify the array, not the variable. Your server only accesses the array when receiving the request, which also happens asynchronously - after the `something` promise resolved.

Comment: Ohhh okay, now I understand! Thanks Bergi!!